# Properly handle nested promise reject

Tags: javascript, promise

What I am trying to do is, first get file from input then read file using file reader and then get image height and width if it is a valid image file.

From `imageProcess` it is showing error by rejecting promise for invalid file type. My concern is i want to reject from `readerProcess` too when `imageProcess` is rejecting. Here I can't be able to reject from `readerProcess` because I am catching `imageProcess` to resolve `readerProcess`.

````
  const target = e.target.name;


  readerProcess(file)
    .then(res => {console.log('reader resuld', res)},
      err => {console.log('error')}
    )

const readerProcess = (file) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    if(file) reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(imageProcess(reader)
      .then(image => {
          return {
            data: reader.result,
            width: image.width,
            height: image.height
          }
        },
        err => reject //i want to reject from here too but catching it from resolve, so it is not rejecting
      ))

  })
}

const imageProcess = (reader) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let img = new Image()
    img.onload = () => resolve(img)
    img.onerror = reject // first reject from here
    img.src = reader.result
  })
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

I'd simplify a bit by having a function whose sole job is to put a promise wrapper around `readFileAsDataURL`:

```
// Promise wrapper for FileReader.prototype.readFileAsDataURL
const readFileAsDataURL(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!file) {
      throw new Error("No file given");
    }
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = reject;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file); // Note: Do this after attaching the handlers, not before
  });
};
```

I'd also amend `imageProcess` to accept the `src` rather than a `FileReader`:

```
const imageProcess = (src) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => resolve(img);
    img.onerror = reject;
    img.src = src;
  });
};
```

Then your `readerProcess` function just chains the promises together:

```
const readerProcess = (file) => {
  return readFileAsDataURL(file)
  .then(imageProcess);
};
```

Usage is as you showed it:

```
readerProcess(file).then(
  res => {console.log('reader resuld', res)},
  err => {console.log('error')}
);
```

Comment: ```const readerProcess = (file) => {
  return readFileAsDataURL(file)
  .then(imageProcess);
};``` how image process src is getting? shouldn't i provide it explicitly or it is getting automatically ?

Comment: @Md.JahidulIslam - It's happening because `.then(imageProcess)` passes `imageProcess` into `then` to set it up as the fulfillment handler. When the promise is fulfilled, the fulfillment handler is called with a single argument: the fulfillment value. In this case, the fulfillment value of `readFileAsDataURL` is the data URL (the `src`) and the fulfillment handler is `imageProcess`. `.then(imageProcess)` is basically `.then(url => imageProcess(url))` but without the unnecessary (in this case) wrapper function.